# DB Connection Slow when using SQJDBC4 Driver on VMWare

Tags: database, performance, connection, vmware

I am facing a peculiar problem.

**Application Details**
Java : Jre 1.6
Db: MS SQL 2008 R2 (On Vmware)
OS: Windows 2008 R2 (On Vmware)

**Problem:** 
Whenever i am trying to connect to the database using sqljdbc4.jar it takes almost 5 seconds to make a connection.
But if i use jtds driver it connects instantly.

Now if i try to connect to a similar database hosted on single physical server it connects instantly using both the drivers.

Please help me if any body has faced this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry.. Had got wrong information about the connection driver being used. Configured the application with sqljdbc4.jar and the issue was resolved.